# Why does code igniter not segregate class types?

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, theory, loader

When you are using code igniter you load a library or model like so

```
$this->load->library('mylibrary');  
$this->load->model('mymodel');
```

So, in a real world example, lets say you have a controller called `user`.

So, to login a user you send them to `http://example.com/user/login`

Now the `login` function loads a form that submits to `http://example.com/user/login_do`
You do some simple checks, and then send it over to your model to do the database check for you.

So you call

```
$this->load->model('user');
if($this->user->validate($email, $pass)){...}
```

---

### UH OH!

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   User in
>   /var/www/unity/src/application/models/User_Model.php
>   on line ...

So what happened? Well, Code igniter does not segregate the classes, so your model now conflicts with your controller,

sure you can use

```
$this->load->model('user_model', '', 'user_m');
if($this->user_m->validate($email, $pass)){...}
```

---

### So, Onto my question.

Why does code igniter not segregate the classes,
e.g. so you would call

```
$this->load->model('user');
if($this->model->user->validate($email, $pass)){...}
```

Sure it's slightly longer, but hell it would make things heaps nicer to user.
is it possible to extend code igniter so it works in this way?

Comment: There's surely a way to change your controller names to something like `User_Controller` or `Controller_User` that will help alleviate the namespace issues (since we never need to call the controller classes by name in our code), probably by extending the Loader or Router, or maybe even just with a route. I was about to check this out myself but I haven't had the time yet. Your question/idea makes sense and I would love to see a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the solution you're asking for (or a great idea), but there's nothing stopping you from doing this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    private $model;
    private $m;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->model->users = $this->user_model;
        $this->m = $this->user_model;
    }

    function index()
    {
        // Here's that syntax you wanted
        $this->model->users->get_many();

        // Even shorter
        $this->m->get_many();
    }

}
```

You can really just assign anything to any property of the controller you want, as long as it's not the name of a loaded class or property (session, router, etc.). It can save you some typing if your model names are really long, but otherwise it's pointless and may conflict with things in the future.

Here's what I do if I'm not using `*_model` for model names:

- Controller name: Users (plural)
- Model name: User (singular)

No conflict, short syntax, sensible naming, it just doesn't work for some names like "news".

As I mentioned, it would be nice to see controller names using something like `Controller_User` or `User_Controller` to clear up the namespace issues a bit for the classes that we actually *do* have to call frequently, like models and libraries, but keep our urls as normal. I'm sure it can be done, something for a rainy day...

Answer (score 1):

You missing the main point, PHP doesn't allow two classes with the same name, basically that's what `Cannot redeclare class User` says.

Comment: But with the way code igniter loads classes could it not do something like `function library($name){
require_once('/libraries/'.$name);
$this->libraries->$name = new $name();
}`

obviously with some changes, but the idea is that the class would be isolated to that function, allowing you to segregate the classes?

Comment: That won't work, test your idea without CI. Btw: I don't feel your change would make things any easier. You have to type more and there aren't any benefits...